# Path of references on a tree structure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a tree structure and maintain a path while traversing the tree.

Here's some code:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct Node {
    children: VecDeque<Node>,
}

struct Cursor<'a> {
    path: VecDeque<&'a mut Node>,
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn new(n: &mut Node) -> Cursor {
        let mut v = VecDeque::new();
        v.push_front(n);
        Cursor { path: v }
    }

    fn go_down(&'a mut self, idx: usize) -> bool {
        let n = match self.path[0].children.get_mut(idx) {
            None => return false,
            Some(x) => x
        };
        self.path.push_front(n);
        true
    }
}
```

I have two questions. First, the lifetime specifier in `go_down()` `self` argument was suggested by the compiler, but I'm not sure why it fixes the reported issue.

Even with this change, however, the above code will not compile because `self.path` is borrowed two times. Is there a way to maintain a path of tree nodes without writing "unsafe" code?

Comment: Why do you need mutable references?

Comment: I would like to modify the nodes.I only need to modify the node on the top of the stack, though, but I wasn't sure how to express this.

I could have a mutable reference to the current node and a stack with immutable references for the path, but then I wouldn't be able to create a mutable reference from the immutable ones when going up the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168919/155423) to [Recursive Data Structures in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167160/155423). The idea is that you operate with owned objects instead of references, and you deconstruct and reconstruct the tree as you traverse it.

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

enum Child { Placeholder, Node(Node) }

struct Node {
    children: Vec<Child>,
}

impl Node {
    fn swap_child(&mut self, idx: usize, c: Child) -> Option<Child> {
        match self.children.get(idx) {
            None => None,
            Some(_) => {
                self.children.push(c);
                Some(self.children.swap_remove(idx))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Cursor {
    node: Node,
    parents: VecDeque<(Node, usize /* index in parent */)>,
}

enum DescendRes { OK(Cursor), Fail(Cursor) }
enum AscendRes  { Done(Node), Cursor(Cursor) }

impl Cursor {
    fn new(n: Node) -> Cursor {
        Cursor { node: n, parents: VecDeque::new() }
    }

    fn descent(mut self, idx: usize) -> DescendRes {
        match self.node.swap_child(idx, Child::Placeholder) {
            None => DescendRes::Fail(self),
            Some(Child::Placeholder) => panic!("This should not happen"),
            Some(Child::Node(child)) => {
                let mut v = self.parents;
                v.push_front((self.node, idx));
                DescendRes::OK(
                    Cursor { node: child, parents: v }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    fn ascend(mut self) -> AscendRes {
        match self.parents.pop_front() {
            None => AscendRes::Done(self.node),
            Some((mut parent, parent_idx)) => {
                match parent.swap_child(parent_idx, Child::Node(self.node)) {
                    Some(Child::Placeholder) => {
                        AscendRes::Cursor(
                            Cursor { node: parent, parents: self.parents }
                        )
                    },
                    _ => panic!("This should not happen")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```