# Save mutable reference for later even when aliased

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, zipper

I'm trying to implement something like a zipper but taking advantage of mutable references to avoid having to deconstruct and reconstruct the data structure as I move through it. I've got example code for an attempt with a linked list, although I'd ideally like to apply it to other structures, like trees.

```
pub enum List<T> {
    Empty,
    Cons { head: T, tail: Box<List<T>> },
}

pub struct Zipper<'a, T: 'a> {
    trail: Option<Box<Zipper<'a, T>>>,
    focus: &'a mut List<T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Zipper<'a, T> {
    pub fn down(&'a mut self) {
        match self.focus {
            &mut List::Empty => (),
            &mut List::Cons {
                tail: ref mut xs, ..
            } => {
                //We need a way to convince rust that we won't use oldZipper
                //until xs goes out of scope
                let oldZipper = std::mem::replace(
                    self,
                    Zipper {
                        trail: None,
                        focus: xs,
                    },
                );
                self.trail = Some(Box::new(oldZipper));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The borrow checker is not happy with this:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:21:21
   |
16 |                 tail: ref mut xs, ..
   |                       ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
21 |                     self,
   |                     ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
30 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

This isn't surprising: if we have a zipper focused on a list and call `down` on it, we get zipper with a mutable reference to the tail of that list, so we have mutable aliasing.

However, if we never use the Zipper's `trail` before `focus` goes out of scope, we'll never be able to "see" the mutable aliasing. This seems analogous to normal mutable borrowing: you can't use the variable you borrowed from until the borrow goes out of scope.

Is there some way to explain this to the borrow checker? If you want to "explain" to the borrow checker that borrowing two non-overlapping slices from an array is okay, you can use [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_at): is there some corresponding function that will enforce that `trail` is never used before `focus` goes out of scope, and in doing so, satisfies the borrow checker?

Comment: Does this [implementation of a zipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168919/155423) answer your question?

Comment: Not really. Implementing a haskell-style zipper, like the one you linked to, seems relatively straightforward. I'm trying to, in addition, avoid disassembling the data structure as you descend, and therefore needing to reassemble it as you ascend.

Comment: I guess examples of answers I'd like are:

"Your analysis is incorrect: if you used unsafe code to implement this it would lead to UB. Here's why",

"Your analysis is correct, but it's impossible to convince the borrow checker, even using unsafe rust",

"Your analysis is correct, but AFAIK nobody's written the unsafe code in a nice library for you", or

"Your analysis is correct, here's the library you want"

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve your goal, we need to get rid of the mutable reference in the `Zipper` struct. We can use mutable raw pointers instead: they let us mutate their referent, and we can more than one such pointer pointing at a particular object, but dereferencing them is unsafe.

Here's the code:

```
use std::mem;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub enum List<T> {
    Empty,
    Cons { head: T, tail: Box<List<T>> },
}

pub struct Zipper<'a, T: 'a> {
    trail: Option<Box<Zipper<'a, T>>>,
    focus: *mut List<T>,
    _list: PhantomData<&'a mut List<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Zipper<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(list: &'a mut List<T>) -> Zipper<'a, T> {
        Zipper {
            trail: None,
            focus: list as *mut List<T>,
            _list: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn down(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            match *self.focus {
                List::Empty => (),
                List::Cons {
                    tail: ref mut xs, ..
                } => {
                    let old_zipper = mem::replace(
                        self,
                        Zipper::new(xs),
                    );
                    self.trail = Some(Box::new(old_zipper));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List::Cons { head: 1, tail: Box::new(List::Empty) };
    let mut zipper = Zipper::new(&mut list);
    zipper.down();
    zipper.down();
}
```

The `focus` field in the `Zipper` struct is now a `*mut List<T>`. Because this is a raw pointer, we can copy it around freely. This resolves the compiler error you had in `Zipper::down`. There's also a new field, `_list`, of type `PhantomData<&'a mut List<T>>`. [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) is a special type that is meant to tell the compiler "pretend I'm storing/owning a `T`, even though I'm not". Without this field, the compiler would complain that the lifetime parameter `'a` is unused.

Notice that `Zipper::new` still expects a `&'a mut List<T>` as a parameter: this allows `Zipper` to provide a safe interface by requiring the caller to have a unique mutable reference to the `List<T>`, a fact we can use to declare that the other unsafe operations in the struct are indeed safe since we have full knowledge of the available mutable references. As far as the compiler is concerned, a `Zipper` *is* mutably borrowing the `List`; if you try to mutate a `List` while a `Zipper` on the `List` is in scope, you'll get an error that the `List` is already mutably borrowed.

---

You haven't shown any code that would let the user get a reference to the `Zipper`'s focus. I've been thinking of a possible implementation that would be unsafe, and it's tempting to go that route, but the compiler won't tell you it's wrong. Let me show you:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Zipper<'a, T> {
    pub fn focus(&mut self) -> &'a mut List<T> {
        unsafe { &mut *self.focus }
    }
}
```

It's tempting to return a `&'a mut List<T>` because that's what we were given. However, it's wrong because the return value's lifetime is not bound to `self` in any way, which means that we could call `focus` twice to obtain two mutable references to the same `List<T>`. If we still had a `&'a mut List<T>` in `Zipper`, the compiler would tell us if we tried to return a `&'a mut List<T>` (unless we used `unsafe` code to work around it). A correct implementation would be:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Zipper<'a, T> {
    pub fn focus(&mut self) -> &mut List<T> {
        unsafe { &mut *self.focus }
    }
}
```

In this implementation, the `Zipper` will be mutably borrowed as long as the returned `&mut List<T>` is around, which means we can't call `focus` (or `down`) until the `&mut List<T>` goes out of scope.

Comment: Is there any reason to use an `&UnsafeCell<>` here rather than a plain `*mut `? The only one I can think of is avoiding `PhantomData`, which is kinda nice, but I am wondering if there are others...

Comment: @MatthieuM. does `*mut T` inform the compiler about the same things that `UnsafeCell` does? There *has* to be some reason for `UnsafeCell` to exist.

Comment: @Shepmaster `UnsafeCell` exists to break the rule that a `T` behind a `&U` (transitively) can be assumed to be immutable; a `T` behind a `&UnsafeCell<U>` cannot be assumed to be immutable. Here, we start with a `&mut T`, so we don't need to use `UnsafeCell` (contrarily to what I did [initially](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47143424/revisions)).

Comment: @Shepmaster: You cannot model `struct A { b: B }` with `b` "mutable" without `UnsafeCell` (pointers here won't work for obvious reasons). Thus, if you wanted to avoid `transmutes` and casts, you could model the `List` using `UnsafeCell` to start with. However, between `*mut T` and `&UnsafeCell<T>` I think the only difference is "borrowing", the `&UnsafeCell<T>` adding a bonus `PhantomData<&(mut?) T>`.