# Cannot borrow x as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am aware what this error means, I just don't have any idea how to solve this puzzle. As a short background - I need a tree structure in my app, I've discovered Rust doesn't play well with circular references, hence I am trying to implement a tree-like data structure myself (but the borrow checker doesn't let me do that either):

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e44e827d5b64fd16ffbbd82f47dcd5ca)

```
struct Node {
    children: Vec<i32>,
}

let mut hm = HashMap::new();

hm.insert(1, Node { children: vec![] });
hm.insert(2, Node { children: vec![1] });

// Let's say I want to remove node 2...
let node = match hm.get(&2) {
    Some(node) => node,
    None => panic!(""),
};

// ...but first I want to remove its children:
for removable in &node.children {
    match hm.get(&removable) {
        Some(_) => hm.remove(&removable), // cannot borrow `hm` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
        None => panic!("Oops, trying to remove data that's not there"),
    };
}
```

How to solve that?

Comment: There're tons of questions about tree structures in Rust. Did you see them?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I googled a bit and I've seen some libraries for making trees. I didn't want to pull a new dependency and thought I'll make a very basic tree. Then I stumbled upon this error. I now have changed my mind and I am going to use a library. However, I am still curious how this basic logic could be handled in Rust. Also, I didn't find a similar-to-mine question.

Comment: I was talking about SO questions: does this answer your question? [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167160/how-do-i-express-mutually-recursive-data-structures-in-safe-rust) especially the Shepmaster's answer.

Comment: how about using `hm.get_mut(&2)`? `node` is an immutable reference, but `.remove()` obviously requires the reference it was invoked on to be mutable. Also, why remove the children explicitly in your example? They'll go out of scope with the removal of node 2 anyways

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Thanks so much for useful links! I am going to read them through.

Comment: @Sty no that doesn't help, unfortunately. Also, `remove()` already has the immutable reference `hm`. `remove` is on `hm`, not on `node`, you are probably confused on that. And... how are children going to go out of scope with the removal of node 2? That even doesn't make sense to me, sorry.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev oh, indeed I parsed that wrong and did not realise that the the entries in the children structs were supposed to be references to other nodes. Have you ever read about [pointers in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html), though? Trees should be recursive data structures and certainly don't benefit from this kind of indirection, so I'd recommend using `Rc<Node>` or something for an actual tree structure

Comment: @Sty Thanks for that advice. I believe `Rc` can't be a solution here, because I'd still need to make mutable reference to the main hashmap at the same time with immutable one. I think I'll go with a crate (I thought it would be easier to implement a basic tree myself, but I was wrong).

Comment: I notice the problem [goes away if you remove the parent first](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0745a2982784cfb6a53aa6911e6c2bb9). Failing that, you can still [extract the children vec using `mem::replace`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c021e19b111385a099ce6564dada81e1).

Comment: @trentcl Wow! Interesting! Finally someone with the actual solution :D Why on earth I didn't think about that myself (I know why, I have been working for 14 hours already). And that `mem::replace` usage, great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! Another quick tip: A `match` that panics on `None` can usually be concisely replaced by a call to `.unwrap()` or `.expect("your error message here")`.

Comment: @trentcl Yep, just noticed and admired that :) However, in my actual app I don't panic so I can't use that unfortunately.