# Nested Dictionary Navigation

Tags: ruby, dictionary, pointers

I have a nested dictionary/hash structure in Ruby like this:

```rb
d = {
 :foo => {
   :hoo => nil,
   :baz => {
     # ...
   },
 },

 :bar => {
   :doo => { 
      # ...
   },
   :loo => nil, 
 },

 # ...
}
```

Every individual dictionary is of unknown size. Its keys are symbols and its values are either `nil` or another dictionary. I am trying to write two methods:

1. `down()` takes the current dictionary and a valid key as arguments and returns a pointer to that value (either nil or another dictionary).
2. `up()` takes the current dictionary and returns a pointer to the outer dictionary it is contained within.

`down()` is straightforward (it is the same as `d[:foo]`), but I am hesitant to just use `d[:foo]` because `up()` is basically impossible without storing some additional structural/navigation information about `d` as `down()` is called.

The return values cannot be a copy of anything in `d`, they must be pointers. I am still confused about which situations are pass-by-value vs pass-by-ref in Ruby, but I do know all of its "effectively a pointer" variables are mutable.

**Update:**

When I say "takes the current dictionary" I am just referring to some variable `dict` such that `dict = d` or `dict = (some child of d)`. `dict` is either a dictionary or nil. For example:

```
d = # ...

dict = down(d, :foo)
# dict is now the current dictionary and points to {:hoo=>nil,:baz=>{}} in d

dict2 = down(dict, :baz)
# down() "takes the current dictionary" (dict) 
# then returns a new current dictionary (dict2)
```

In my attempts at a solution, it has seemed essential that some additional entity is keeping track of the level at which the current dictionary resides.

Comment: I've removed the unrelated information about your future Rust port — questions should be focused. When you get there, you may be interested in [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168919/155423)

Comment: When you say "takes the current dictionary" is the current dictionary, or for that matter, any dictionary, described by an array such as `[:foo, :hoo]` or are all the keys at all the levels unique, so that, for example, if `:goo` is a dictionary we need to keep track of its ancestors? It might be more convenient to write `:hoo=>[]` rather than `:hoo=>nil` if it has no children.

Comment: @CarySwoveland When I say "the current dictionary" I just mean its a variable pointing to some dictionary inside `d`. Also if `:hoo=>[]` is better I have no special reason to use `nil` so by all means...

Comment: You may wish to look at [Is Ruby pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](https://mixandgo.com/learn/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What do you mean by "pointer"? Ruby does not have a concept called "pointer", so if you are introducing your own concepts, you need to provide a clear, objective, complete, precise, unambiguous definition of what you mean by that concept, otherwise it will be impossible to answer the question. Also, you wrote "I am still confused about which situations are pass-by-value vs pass-by-ref in Ruby", but there is actually nothing confusing about this, since Ruby simply does not support pass-by-reference at all, so *all* situations are *always* pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I fully understand the question but perhaps you are looking for something like the following, which is just a linked list and not a nested hash of dictionaries, but I think this is more typical of what is done in Ruby.

```
class Dictionary
  attr_accessor :name, :up, :down
  def initialize(name, up)
    @name = name
    @up = up
    @down = []
    up.down << self unless up.nil?
  end
end
```

We begin by creating the top Dictionary.

```
top = Dictionary.new("top", nil)
  #=> #<Dictionary:0x000056dd361bcd48 @name="top", @up=nil, @down=[]>
```

Now let's create a child of `top`.

```
top_foo = Dictionary.new("foo", top)
  #=> #<Dictionary:0x000056dd361ce458 @name="foo",
  #     @up=#<Dictionary:0x000056dd361bcd48 @name="top", @up=nil,
  #       @down=[#<Dictionary:0x000056dd361ce458 ...>]>,
  #     @down=[]>
```

Look at return value carefully. The value of `top_foo`'s instance variable `@up` is the instance of `Dictionary` named `top`. We can see this more clearly as follows:

```
top_foo.up.name
  #=> "top"
top_foo.down
  #=> []
```

Let's see how `top.down` (formerly an empty array) has changed.

```
top.down.map(&:name)
  #=> ["foo"]
```

Now create another child of `top`.

```
top_goo = Dictionary.new("goo", top)
  #=> #<Dictionary:0x000056dd3611a480 @name="goo",
  #     @up=#<Dictionary:0x000056dd35eed180 @name="top",...
  #     @down=[]> 
top_goo.up.name
  #=> "top" 
top_goo.down
  #=> []
```

```
top.down.map(&:name)
  #=> ["foo", "goo"]
```

Now create a child of `top_foo`:

```
top_foo_who = Dictionary.new("who", top_foo)
  #=> #<Dictionary:0x000056dd36171488 @name="who",
  #     @up=#<top_foo instance>
```

```
top_foo_who.name
  #=> "who"
top_foo_who.up.name
  #=> "foo"
top_foo_who.down
  #=> []
```

```
top_foo.down.map(&:name)
  #=> "foo"
```

Suppose we wish to go from `top_foo_who` to `top`.

```
start = top_foo_who
dict = loop do
  break start if start.up.nil?
  start = start.up
end
  #=> #<Dictionary:...>
```

```
dict.name
  #=> "top" 
dict.down.map(&:name)
  #=> ["foo", "goo"]
```

If we wanted to go from `top` to `top_foo`, by the name `"foo"`, we could write:

```
idx = top.down.map(&:name).index("foo")
  #=> 0
dict = top.down[idx]      
  #=> #<Dictionary...>
dict.name
  #=> "foo"
```