# Idiomatic Way to Handle Struct Fields that Reference the Parent

Tags: rust

While porting an application from Python to Rust I ran into this problem.

If we have classes like this:

```py
class Backend:
    def __init__(self, result_consumer=None):
        self.result_consumer = ResultConsumer(self, ..)
    
class ResultConsumer:
    def __init__(self, backend=None):
        self.backend=backend
```

and ResultConsumer is regularly calling methods like `self.backend.method()` and Backend is also calling methods like `self.result_consumer.method()`.

In Rust you can't just use struct fields to establish such a relationship.

I tried an approach with generics (as ResultConsumer should support multiple backends)

```
struct ResultConsumer<B: Backend> {
    backend: Arc<B>,
}
struct Backend {
    result_consumer: ResultConsumer<Self>
}
```

what would be the most idiomatic way to represent this relationship in Rust?  Is my example approach viable?

I am asking specifically, because while it compiles I cannot figure out how to populate the `ResultConsumer` in the `result_consumer` field for `Backend` when I construct it.

Comment: use `Rc` or just avoid this kind of pattern

Comment: Related: [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167160/how-do-i-express-mutually-recursive-data-structures-in-safe-rust)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you can use something like the following

```rust
struct ResultConsumer {
    backend: RefCell<Weak<Backend>>,
}
struct Backend {
    result_consumer: RefCell<Rc<ResultConsumer>>,
}

impl Backend {
    fn new() -> Rc<Backend> {
        println!("Backend::new");
        let mut b_rc = Rc::new(Backend {
            result_consumer: RefCell::new(Rc::new(ResultConsumer {
                backend: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
            })),
        });

        *b_rc.result_consumer.borrow().backend.borrow_mut() = Rc::downgrade(&b_rc);
        b_rc
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the `Rc` should probably be a `Weak` to break the reference cycle.

Comment: No it doesn't, with your code `drop (Backend::new())` will leak: the backend is not freed because the consumer points to it, and the consumer is not freed because the backend points to it. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac9dbff67631ece3f3b56eab87eaf8e6)

Comment: @Jmb thank u. edited