# Expected struct but found mutable reference to struct

Tags: rust

I created a type `Space` that has an optional fields `lef_neighbor` and `right_neighbor` of the same type `Space`. Rust needs to know the size of the type at compile time so I wrapped the types in a `Box<>`. I now want to create a method that I can call on a `Space` that creates the `right_neighbor` of this `Space` object and assigns it as such. It also needs to set the `left_neighbor` field of the new `Space` to the old `Space` so they can both find each other.

```
pub struct Space {
    left_neighbor: Option<Box<Space>>,
    right_neighbor: Option<Box<Space>>,
}

impl Space {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            left_neighbor: None,
            right_neighbor: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn create_neigbor(&mut self) {
        let neighbor_space = Space::new();
        neighbor_space.left_neighbor = Some(Box::new(self));
        self.right_neighbor = Some(Box::new(neighbor_space));
    }
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04ea491c896661e8e3bcb1e228afd47c))

This gives the compile error:

```
   |
16 |         neighbor_space.left_neighbor = Some(Box::new(self));
   |                                                      ^^^^ expected struct `Space`, found `&mut Space`
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167160/how-do-i-express-mutually-recursive-data-structures-in-safe-rust)

Comment: `Box<Space>` is a smart pointer that points to a heap-allocated `Space` and *owns* it (i.e. drops it when the `Box` is dropped). You are trying to create a `Box<Space>` using a reference to `Space`, which is a different thing. Rust has no GC, so an object and a reference to an object are very different thing because the former is owned, while the latter is just borrowed.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what you are making is similar to a Doubly Linked List. Doubly Linked Lists are notoriously hard to do in safe rust. I recommend giving a read to [Learning Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

As a TLDR, you can use either raw pointers and unsafe, or store your spaces in an external storage (a vector, or something) and use indices into that space as a proxy to the actual thing, or use Rc/Arc instead of Box (though this will be probably lead to memory leaks, unless you properly use weak refs and such).