# Mutably borrowing last initialized node of a tree

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

##### I am trying to lazy-initialize a simple tree on first access of a node.

My tree struct:

```
struct Tree {
    true_branch: Option<Box<Tree>>,
    false_branch: Option<Box<Tree>>,
}
```

To do the lazy initialization on first access I would like to return a `Result<&mut Tree, &mut Tree>` which is an `Ok(requested_node)` if the node is already initialized or an `Err(last_initialized_on_the_path_to_requested_node)` so that the lazy initialization can continue from that node.

Getting a node, if it initialized works fine with `get_mut` but I cannot get the `Result` version, `get_last_initialized_mut`, to compile.

```
impl Tree {
    fn get_mut(&mut self, mut directions: impl Iterator<Item = bool>) -> Option<&mut Self> {
        let mut current = self;
        loop {
            match directions.next() {
                None => break,
                Some(true) => {
                    current = current.true_branch.as_deref_mut()?;
                }
                Some(false) => {
                    current = current.false_branch.as_deref_mut()?;
                }
            }
        }
        Some(current)
    }
    
    /// This does not compile
    fn get_last_initialized_mut(&mut self, mut directions: impl Iterator<Item = bool>) -> Result<&mut Self, &mut Self> {
        let mut current = self;
        loop {
            match directions.next() {
                None => break,
                Some(true) => {
                    let next = current.true_branch.as_deref_mut();
                    if next.is_none() {
                        drop(next);
                        return Err(current);
                    } else {
                        current = next.unwrap();
                    }
                }
                Some(false) => {
                    let next = current.false_branch.as_deref_mut();
                    if next.is_none() {
                        drop(next);
                        return Err(current);
                    } else {
                        current = next.unwrap();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(current)
    }
}
```

#### The error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*current` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:36:36
   |
27 |     fn get_last_initialized_mut(&mut self, mut directions: impl Iterator<Item = bool>) -> Result<&mut Self, &mut Self> {
   |                                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
33 |                     let next = current.true_branch.as_deref_mut();
   |                                ---------------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
36 |                         return Err(current);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
52 |         Ok(current)
   |         ----------- returning this value requires that `current.true_branch` is borrowed for `'1`
```

What I do not get is that I drop `next` on line 35 and then it says `current` is still borrowed on line 36, by the borrow by `next` on line 33.

I have tried breaking with an enum and returning outside of the loop based on the break type, dropping variables. Neither of them worked.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99469ca3cfaf2b0668dbe8744414b5cf)

Comment: This is sadly a known [limitation of the NLL rules](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/latest/polonius_the_crab/#rationale-limitations-of-the-nll-borrow-checker) and there isn't a great canonical workaround for it. I've not done an in-depth analysis, but if you've checked this for soundness, and can't come up with a different API, you can resort to `unsafe` to promise the compiler this is okay.

Comment: I tried everything I could come up with and yeas, the borrow checker expand some lifetime after some return and it broke what you want to do, so you will need some unsafe:

[playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bef3e248f9bb309547114af62b16cdca)

Comment: Mutually recursive data types in rust are hard, here's a few pointers and ways to implement what you're trying to achieve without `unsafe`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45109686/490790

Comment: Thanks! The problem is as @isaactfa said an NLL limitation, [the first one in the rule list](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663). Currently I use the workaround of returning a `Result<&mut Tree, TreeIndex>` then looking up the `Err(index)` variant with `get_mut`, which is not ideal but works. If it ever becomes a performance bottleneck `unsafe` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of match arm of your original program, the lifetime of `next`, which borrows `current`, ends at least until the match arm block ends:

```
let next = current.true_branch.as_deref_mut();
// borrow starts
if next.is_none() {
    drop(next);
    return Err(current);
} else {
    current = next.unwrap();
}
// borrow ends
```

We can make a workaround by limiting the lifetime of next into an `if let` statement, since we would check the `Option` enum:

```
if let Some(ref mut next) = current.true_branch {
    // borrow of `current` only spans in this block
    current = next;
} else {
    // `current` is NOT borrowed here
    return Err(current);
}
```

Now, the borrow of `current` only spans in the true branch of the `if let` statment. In the `else` branch, `current` is NOT borrowed. This means we can safely return `current` in the `else` branch.

reproducible Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=083e5901c967a764ed367bb58aab27fb

Comment: Thanks! Today I learned that using `ref` and `ref mut` in patterns actually has some other use than syntactic sugar. I always used `current.true_branch.as_mut()` style code to match references, which does not compile.