# How to create Tree Zipper using Rust?

Tags: rust, binary-tree, zipper

I am trying to create a [Tree Zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) using Rust. It is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168919/213269) but I am using struct fields instead of `Vec` for the childs.

I want to have a tree of nodes, e.g.:

```
    7
   / \
  4   11
 /
2
```

The point of using a Zipper is that the "current" Node should be mutable. And that this should be implemented without `unsafe` blocks.

I declared my `Node` and `NodeZipper` as below:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn navigate(self) -> NodeZipper {
        NodeZipper {
            node: self,
            parent: None,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NodeZipper {
    node: Node,
    parent: Option<Box<NodeZipper>>,
}

impl NodeZipper {
    fn left(mut self) -> Self {
        let left_child = self.node.left.take().unwrap(); // take() mutates the node
        Self {
            node: *left_child,
            parent: Some(Box::new(self)),
        }
    }

    fn parent(mut self) -> Self {
        let parent = self.parent.take().unwrap();
        Self {
            node: parent.node,
            parent: parent.parent,
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that I use `.take()` and it mutates the `Node`, so some data is lost. Is there an alternative way to solve this without using e.g. clone and at least without using `unsafe`?

Here is a sample run, where I navigate from the root, down to the left child, and then back to the parent (but now the left child is lost).

```
fn main() {
    let tree = Node {
        value: 7,
        left: Some(Box::new(Node {
            value: 4,
            left: Some(Box::new(Node {
                value: 2,
                left: None,
                right: None,
            })),
            right: None,
        })),
        right: Some(Box::new(Node {
            value: 11,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })),
    };
    
    let nav = tree.navigate();
    println!("t: {:?}", nav);

    let nav = nav.left();
    println!("t: {:?}", nav);

    let nav = nav.parent();
    println!("t: {:?}", nav);
}
```

And the output where the *left child* of the *root* is lost, when moving back to the parent:

```
t: NodeZipper { node: Node { value: 7, left: Some(Node { value: 4, left: Some(Node { value: 2, left: None, right: None }), right: None }), right: Some(Node { value: 11, left: None, right: None }) }, parent: None }
t: NodeZipper { node: Node { value: 4, left: Some(Node { value: 2, left: None, right: None }), right: None }, parent: Some(NodeZipper { node: Node { value: 7, left: None, right: Some(Node { value: 11, left: None, right: None }) }, parent: None }) }
t: NodeZipper { node: Node { value: 7, left: None, right: Some(Node { value: 11, left: None, right: None }) }, parent: None }
```

Comment: I mean the obvious error is not putting back the nodes you took. You'll have to store them and put them back when you navigate back. Maybe `node` needs to be a stack of nodes with the current one at the very top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean the obvious error is not putting back the nodes you took. You'll have to store them and put them back when you navigate back.

yes, that is correct. I also lacked understanding of how [Zippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) should work. But I have got more insight now.

I ended up with a `parent()` method as below, that also puts back the child node when traversing upwards.

```
fn parent(mut self) -> Option<Self> {
    match self.parent.take() {
        None => None,
        Some(parent_ref) => {
            let (mut parent, side) = *parent_ref;
            match side {
                ChildSide::Left => {
                   // put back what we took using `take()` while traversing down
                    parent.node.left = Some(Box::new(self.node));
                    Some(Self {
                        node: parent.node,
                        parent: parent.parent,
                    })
                }
                ChildSide::Right => {
                   // put back what we took using `take()` while traversing down
                    parent.node.right = Some(Box::new(self.node));
                    Some(Self {
                        node: parent.node,
                        parent: parent.parent,
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `NodeZipper` now declared as:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NodeZipper {
    node: Node,
    parent: Option<Box<(NodeZipper, ChildSide)>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ChildSide {
    Left,
    Right,
}
```